# SEARCHING FOR A LIST OF USERS LOGIN TIME IN LDAP CONTAINER

Tags: docker, ldap, containers, ldap-query

I have been trying to get a login time stamp of some users on my ldap container but it seems difficult at the moment i can only generate for a single user while attempting to use more than a single user isn't returning anything for me but error. i did try using operators too but still the same.

> `ldapsearch -h localhost -D cn=Manager,dc=lab,dc=zec -w sixslatekays -b ou=People,cn=wpn,ou=Domains,dc=lab,dc=zec "(CN=oluwasode)" cn loginTime pwdaccountlockedtime l`

i need help in taken the same for a multiple entries.

Comment: Without returning anything but *what* error?

Comment: I am not able to generate the same error now  but the execution was breaking at 
` "(|(CN=oluwasode)(CN=nazehs))" ` 
and now  the and the below  is fetching the login for both users  but I was wondering if there is a better way of fetching the same other than then below multiple users
`ldapsearch -h localhost -D cn=Manager,dc=lab,dc=zec -w sixslatekays -b ou=People,cn=wpn,ou=Domains,dc=lab,dc=zec "(|(CN=oluwasode)(CN=nazehs))" cn loginTime pwdaccountlockedtime l `

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
ldapsearch -h localhost -D cn=Manager,dc=lab,dc=zec -w sixslatekays -b ou=People,cn=wpn,ou=Domains,dc=lab,dc=zec "(objectClass=person)" cn loginTime pwdaccountlockedtime l
```

Comment: i needed to fetch the same for some users not all users